# Why can't python import a simple function from a module I created?

Tags: python, numpy, module

I am trying to do a bit of math not covered under the numpy or scipy packages. Since I have to do these calculations many times, I thought I'd create my own function in my own *mathystuff.py* module and import it into my workspace. Easy enough, except python doesn't like importing the function! Here's what I did:

First, I created my file *mathystuff.py* which is located in my *venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/* folder like the rest of my modules.

```
import numpy as np

def mathfunction(input1, input2):
     #do some math calculations here - lots of np.stuff()
     #and some more math calculations here, you get it
     return answer
```

Simple as that. In my main project, I simply call:

```
from mathystuff import mathfunction
```

where I'm met with the error `cannot import name 'mathfunction' from 'mathystuff'` pointing me to the correct location of the *.py* file. I've done this a million times before and even done this with other modules I've made in the same project, so why would this happen?

Comment: Can you indicate your file/folder structure?

Comment: You could try `import mathystuff; print(dir(mathystuff))` to check if everything is right (e. g. no typo).

Comment: Is main project the same directory as your _mathystuff.py_ file?

Comment: @MichaelButscher it works if I just call `import mathystuff` and then do `mathystuff.mathfunction()` so I'll just leave it like that. No idea why it didn't like it how I did it originally.

Comment: Maybe you moved the file and renamed the function without closing the active Python process (IPython console, Jupyter Notebook, etc.)? In that case, try restarting your Python kernel.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons, but according to limited information provided I will go with the ones I think are most possible. (PS I would've commented to ask questions but unfortunately I don't have enough rep).

Check if:

- Your virtual env is activated. (I know it sounds silly but it is possible to forget activating venv)
- If it's active, then check the location of python by typing `which python` into terminal (or `which python3` if you are running your code with `python3`). This will return the directory python (eg: `path/to/folder/venv/bin/python3`). While working on multiple venvs, it's easy to get confused and work on `venvA` while `venvB` is active.
- If all above checks, go into *venv/lib/* directory and confirm that you have only one python directory there. Like *venv/lib/python3.8* **or** *venv/lib/python3.7*. If, for some reason, there are two (or more) python versions in venv/lib/ then make sure the one you use is the one your module is located in.

These are the most common errors I came across so far.